# Can I ask this question? Is it possible to calculate the velocity of a surface to air missile?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I was wondering if it is possible to calculate the velocity of a surface to air missile like the THAAD missile system?

Comment: Why this question wasn't migrated to physics stack exchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, if you're not sure if a question can be asked or not, just ask it. It may *sound* like we're being harsh when (if) we tell you it's off topic, but we won't hold it against you.

But since you asked, this question sounds like it would be off topic for us.

Comment: Thank You. But if the questions of any poster is repeatedly  down voted for being off topic that poster will be banned right?

Comment: @D_S For users who repeatedly ask off-topic questions, this can happen; read more [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/). This has very specific effects, it is different from a [suspension](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), it is triggered by long streaks of poor questions, and [you get warned before it happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118). A single bad question will not get you banned.

Comment: (On the other hand, if you get a quality warning after six posts on missile systems or such, you should ask yourself whether this site is where you should be asking that stuff.)